# Tokenize devnagari words into letters

Tags: java, split, cpu-word, hindi

I have something like

```
a = "बिक्रम मेरो नाम हो"
```

I want to achieve something like in Java

```
a[0] = बि 
a[1] = क्र 
a[3] = म
```

Comment: Are you working in `Hindi` language?

Comment: Did you tried String.toCharArray() ?

Comment: Do you want to replace the values, or get their value?

Comment: @sneha  http://ideone.com/vCqkKS  Something like this we can get but I have no clue how to group this hindi  letters :-/

Comment: I think this you are looking for this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25398990/222861

Answer (score 0):

Java internally stores each character of any language in UTF-16(2 bytes) so you can safely access the characters individually.

Comment: The issue is that the "visual" letter बि is actually a ligature of two Unicode characters  ि and ब - the question isn't about accessing the individual `char` values but about how to group the combining characters together.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
             String a = "बिक्रम मेरो नाम हो";
             int strLen = a.length();
             char array[] = new char[strLen];
             String strArray1[] = new String[strLen];
             for (int i=0 ; i< strLen ; i++)
             {
                 array[i] = a.charAt(i);
                 strArray1[i] = Character.toString(a.charAt(i));
                 System.out.println ("Index = " + i + "* Char = " +array[i] + "** String =" +strArray1[i] );

             }
```

**Output:**

```
Index = 0* Char = ब** String =ब
Index = 1* Char = ि** String =ि
Index = 2* Char = क** String =क
Index = 3* Char = ्** String =्
Index = 4* Char = र** String =र
Index = 5* Char = म** String =म
Index = 6* Char =  ** String = 
Index = 7* Char = म** String =म
Index = 8* Char = े** String =े
Index = 9* Char = र** String =र
Index = 10* Char = ो** String =ो
Index = 11* Char =  ** String = 
Index = 12* Char = न** String =न
Index = 13* Char = ा** String =ा
Index = 14* Char = म** String =म
Index = 15* Char =  ** String = 
Index = 16* Char = ह** String =ह
Index = 17* Char = ो** String =ो
```

**Note:**

In order to allow eclipse to allow you to save your java program with foreign characters(Hindi alphabets), do the following:

Go to:
"**Windows > Preferences > General > Content Types > Text > {Choose file type}
{Selected file type} > Default encoding > UTF-8**" and click *Update*.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try icu4j?

[BreakIterator character instance](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/BreakIterator.html#getCharacterInstance()) has a possibility to split String to characters

Answer (score 0):

My code is not at all optimized, sorry about that but it works!

Just change the path of the file in which you are going to enter the devnagri sentence and it should work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{


    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/ubuntu/Documents/trainforjava.txt"));   //PLEASE ENTER PATH HERE

     String[] devFull = new String[]{

             "अ","आ", "इ", "ई", "उ", "ऊ", "ऋ"
             , "ऌ" ,"ऍ",  "ए", "ऐ", "ऑ", "ओ", "औ",


             "क", "ख", "ग", "घ" ,"ङ",
             "च" ,"छ" ,"ज"," झ"," ञ",
             "ट","ठ", "ड"," ढ"," ण",
             "त", "थ", "द", "ध", "न",
             "प", "फ", "ब"," भ","म",
             "य", "र", "ल", "ळ",
             "व", "श" ,"ष","स" ,"ह"


        };

     String[] uniDev = new String[]
             {
                     "905","906","907","908","909","90a","90b",
                     "90c","90d","90f","910","911","913","914",
                     "915","916","917","918","919",
                     "91a","91b","91c","91d","91e",
                     "91f","920","921","922","923",
                     "924","925","926","927","928",
                     "92a","92b","92c","92d","92e",
                     "92f","930","932","933",
                     "935","936","937","938","939"
             };






     String[] devHalf = new String[]
             {
                     "$़","ऽ","$ा","$ि" ,
                     "$ी", "$ ु","$ू","$ृ","$ॄ","$ॅ",
                     "$े","$ै","$ॉ",
                     "$ो","$ौ"
             };


     String[] gujHalf = new String[]
             {

                     "$઼","ઽ","$ા","$િ"  ,
                "$ી","$ુ","$ૂ","$ૃ","$ૄ","$ૅ",
                "$ે","$ૈ","$ૉ",
                "$ો","$ૌ"


             };


    try
    {
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while( (line = br.readLine() ) != null)
            {
                line=line.replaceAll(" ", "");  //remove white spaces if any 
                System.out.println();
                //System.out.println(line);

                 int strLength = line.length();

                // String a = "बिक्रम मेरो नाम हो";
                 int strLen = line.length();
                 char array[] = new char[strLen];
                 String strArray1[] = new String[strLen];
                 int mark[] = new int[strLen+1];
                 String unis[]=new String[strLen];
                 int cnt=0;
                 String newCharD[]=new String [strLen];
                 String newCharG[]=new String [strLen];
                 String tempD=null;
                 String tempG=null;
                 String arr = null;
                 String next =null;
                 String temp=null;
                 String uniNext=null;
                 int hold=0;
                 int j=0;

                 for (int i=0 ; i< strLen ; i++)
                 {
                     j=i+1;
                     array[i] = line.charAt(i);

                     strArray1[i] = Character.toString(line.charAt(i));

                     if(i<(strLen-1))
                     {
                         char nbit = line.charAt(j);
                         next=Character.toString(line.charAt(j));
                         uniNext=Integer.toHexString(nbit);
                         //System.out.print("\nUninext:\t"+uniNext);
                     }
                     unis[i]=Integer.toHexString(array[i]); 
                                             mark[strLen]=1;
                     if((Arrays.asList(devFull).contains(Character.toString(array[i]))) && (!uniNext.equalsIgnoreCase("94d"))  )
                     {
                         mark[i]=1;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         mark[i]=0;
                     }


                     //
                 //System.out.println();
                     //System.out.println ("Index = " + i + "* Char = " +array[i] + "** String =" +strArray1[i]+ "Unicode="+unis[i]+"Mark="+mark[i]);
                     //System.out.print(unis[i].toString());



                 }

                 int start=0;
                 start=0;
                 for(int l1=0;l1<=strLen;l1++)
                 {
                     //start=0;

                     if(l1==0)
                     {
                         temp=Character.toString(array[l1]);

                     }

                     else
                     {
                         if(mark[l1]==0)
                         {
                             temp=temp+Character.toString(array[l1]);
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             System.out.print(" "+temp);
                             newCharD[start]=temp;
                             start++;
                             temp=null;
                             if(l1!=strLen)
                             {
                                 temp=Character.toString(array[l1]);     
                             }

                         }
                     }
                 }


                /* for(int s=0;s<start;s++)
                 {
                     System.out.print(" "+newCharD[s]);      
                 }*/


                 for(int s=0;s<start;s++)
                 {

                 }


            }
    }
     finally {
            br.close();
        }
    //PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new //FileOutputStream("/home/ubuntu/Documents/trainforjavaoutput.txt"));
    //System.setOut(out);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this for Hindi :-**

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.text.BreakIterator;
    import java.util.Locale;
    
    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
    
            String text = "बिक्रम मेरो नाम हो";
            Locale hindi = new Locale("hi", "IN");
            BreakIterator breaker = BreakIterator.getCharacterInstance(hindi);
            breaker.setText(text);
            int start = breaker.first();
            for (int end = breaker.next();
                 end != BreakIterator.DONE;
                 start = end, end = breaker.next()) {
                System.out.println(text.substring(start,end));
            }
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT:-**

```
बि
क्र
म
 
मे
रो
 
ना
म
 
हो
```

> **BreakIterator Java Documentation:** https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/about.html

Answer (score -1):

In order to split the string by letters rather than characters, going by dvasanth's suggestion, you can try below:

```
     String x = "बिक्रम मेरो नाम हो";
         x=x.replaceAll(" ", ""); // Remove all spaces
         int strLength = x.length();
                 String [] letterArray = new String (strLength /2);
         String combined = "";
         for (int i=0, j=0; i < strLength ; i=i+2,j++)
         {
            strArray1[i] = Character.toString(x.charAt(i));
            if (i+1 < strLength)
            {
                strArray1[i+1] = Character.toString(x.charAt(i+1));
                combined = strArray1[i]+strArray1[i+1]; // This line provides the letters.
                           // Assumption is that each letter is 2 unicode characters long.

            }
            else
            {
                combined = strArray1[i];
            }
            letterArray [j] = combined; 
            System.out.println("Split string by letters is : "+combined);
                    System.out.println("Split string by letters in array is : "+letterArray [j]);
         }
```

**Output is:**

```
Split string by letters is : बि
Split string by letters is : क्
Split string by letters is : रम
Split string by letters is : मे
Split string by letters is : रो
Split string by letters is : ना
Split string by letters is : मह
Split string by letters is : ो
```

Note:

In order to allow eclipse to allow you to save your java program with foreign characters(Hindi alphabets), do the following:

Go to:
"**Windows > Preferences > General > Content Types > Text > {Choose file type}
{Selected file type} > Default encoding > UTF-8**" and click *Update*.

Comment: Thanks for answer.but output is partially correct. I want to store every letter at different index in array.

Comment: @sneha: change the variable `combined` as an array instead of string and you can achieve the result.

Comment: @sneha: Refer my updated answer. I have included an array called `letterArray` which is an array containing letters at different index. Hope it helps