# split hindi word maintaining conjuncts using javascript

Tags: javascript, utf-8

i am trying out bellow code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the array values after the split.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "कसौटी";
    var res = str.split("");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

my result should be `क, सौ, टी`

however it turns out to be `क,स,ौ,ट,ी`

what exactly can be done to get the above result

is there a way to split hindi character while maintaing the conjuncts

any way in which we split utf -8 encoded characters then merge them back to get above result

please provide details in code , on how exactly it can be done

Comment: I think this answer you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/25398990/222861